# How to crop image in oval shape or facemask shape in android?

Tags: android, camera

I am doing camera application.i have capture and crop image in square shape. But i need  oval shape or human face shape. How is it come ?

Answer (score 6):

I have used following method and passed my captured bitmap image to this method. And it will work.

```
public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
        int targetWidth = 125;
        int targetHeight = 125;

        Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth,
                targetHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
        Path path = new Path();
        path.addCircle(
                ((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
                ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
                (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
                Path.Direction.CCW);

        canvas.clipPath(path);
        Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
        canvas.drawBitmap(
                sourceBitmap,
                new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap
                        .getHeight()), new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth,
                        targetHeight), p);
        return targetBitmap;
    }
```

And the output is as follows:-
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I used following in one of my project. May be this helps you.

```
public  Drawable getRoundedCornerImage(Drawable bitmapDrawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)bitmapDrawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = 10;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(output);
        return image;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Explore [com.android.camera.CropImage.java sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/1.5_r4/com/android/camera/CropImage.java). It can crop circle images.

```
    // if we're circle cropping we'll want alpha which is the third param here
    464    mCroppedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
    465                    mCircleCrop ?
    466                            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 :
    467                            Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    468    Canvas c1 = new Canvas(mCroppedImage);
    469    c1.drawBitmap(mBitmap, r, new Rect(0, 0, width, height), null);
    470
    471    if (mCircleCrop) {
    472        // OK, so what's all this about?
    473        // Bitmaps are inherently rectangular but we want to return something
    474        // that's basically a circle.  So we fill in the area around the circle
    475        // with alpha.  Note the all important PortDuff.Mode.CLEAR.
    476        Canvas c = new Canvas (mCroppedImage);
    477        android.graphics.Path p = new android.graphics.Path();
    478        p.addCircle(width/2F, height/2F, width/2F, android.graphics.Path.Direction.CW);
    479        c.clipPath(p, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
    480
    481        fillCanvas(width, height, c);
    482    }
```

Answer (score 2):

@vokilam you are right; I just explored into code and found a way to work around...

Just include this line in the main Activity
`intent.putExtra(CropImage.CIRCLE_CROP, "circleCrop");`

But you will only get circles, not oval; so @amarnathreddy you cannot cut perfect human face with this; instead go for [Grabcut of OpenCv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173187/how-do-you-cut-a-face-out-of-an-image)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this ...to crop in human face shape

```
Uri ImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("filepath"); 
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); 
intent.setType("image/*"); 
intent.setData(ImageCaptureUri); 
intent.putExtra("outputX", 200); 
intent.putExtra("outputY", 200); 
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1); 
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1); 
intent.putExtra("scale", true); 
intent.putExtra("return-data", true); 
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: it is asking com.android.gallery class

Comment: intent.setComponent( new ComponentName("com.android.camera" ,"com.android.camera.CropImage"));